# How to delete orphan temp tables in Postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I noticed in my log a few entries about

```
autovacuum: found orphan temp table "pg_temp_35"."sometable" in database "mydb"
```

I tried to drop them but got:

```
(could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  could not open file "base/19269/t24_752462": No such file or directory)
```

I've read on the mailing lists that this is a known possibility and that the developers don't want the server to just delete the orphaned tables automatically but I can't find info on how to fix the error that I'm actually getting.

Comment: Check this one: `http://www.jkdba.com/postgres-orphaned-temp-tables-after-baserestore/`

Comment: @SQLadmin that doesn't address my problem which is that my tables don't want to be dropped (or are already dropped but the DB still thinks they exist somewhere in a file that it can't find).